# How to fix Google Chrome's "He's dead, Jim!" error?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10

I'm getting the following error every time Chrome launched:

> #### He's dead, Jim!
>
> The webpage was terminated unexpectedly. To continue, reload or go to another page.

It doesn't matter whether I opened a new tab, `chrome://settings/` or restart the computer.

[image]

I have tried uninstall and reinstall, removed Appdata before uninstalling.
The version is most probably 44.0.2403.155 m (64-bit). I have tried installing Google Chrome Canary too, but getting the same error as this one.

Any help on solving this issue would be much appreciable.

**Update:**
I have installed the 32 bit version of Chrome and it's working fine.
Then tried installing the 64-bit version again. It shows same error again.

Comment: What is your memory usage like on Windows when Chrome is open? Also see here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1270364

Comment: do you use SSD?

Comment: @MC10 I have 8GB RAM installed. It's average of 40% of total usage while Chrome is open.

Comment: @Chin Yes, my OS is installed on it.

Answer (score 3):

Often, if I leave my computer on for a while, Chrome processes build up and I get the "He's dead, Jim!" message. Since I have Drive, Hangouts, and Photos running processes even when I'm offline, I don't even have to open the browser for Chrome to be stockpiling memory. Certain sites (such as Imgur) can make this even worse and don't get me started on Flash.

First, press Shift+Esc to see the Task Manager inside Chrome and check your memory usage (hopefully that will still come up). Extensions can be memory hogs and bring everything else down with them. If that's bad, see where the problem is. If not, or you can't get to it, check your machine's Task Manager as well. If memory use is bad there and you have any of the Google apps installed, try disabling them on start up and restarting your computer again (so that they aren't running).

Comment: Currently there are no extensions installed on my Chrome. I have Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and downloaded the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: With 8GB, Chrome should run for a while, even if it's continually claiming more memory. Your (probable) version is the same as mine which runs fine on my older 64 bit laptop. If you're happy with the 32 bit version, I guess that's a solution. Otherwise I'd check that Windows isn't set to always treat Chrome as a 32 bit application for some reason.